# Installing ia32-libs on karmic koala

Tags: apt, 9.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I keep using Ubuntu 9.04 if it's outdated?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90929/can-i-keep-using-ubuntu-9-04-if-its-outdated)
>   [Unable to install software on my ubuntu 9.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/unable-to-install-software-on-my-ubuntu-9-10)

This server I'm running is still on Karmic - I'm painfully aware that it has reached its end of life. However, due to a RAID driver we're using it's a pretty big hassle to upgrade, something that I haven't yet had time to look into.

I'm trying to run a Ventrilo server, and I'm stuck because I can't install `ia32-libs`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  lib32asound2 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6 lib32v4l-0 lib32z1 libc6-i386
Suggested packages:
  lib32asound2-plugins
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ia32-libs lib32asound2 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6 lib32v4l-0 lib32z1 libc6-i386
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 33.8MB of archives.
After this operation, 143MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libc6-i386 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32gcc1 lib32z1 lib32stdc++6 lib32asound2 lib32ncurses5 lib32v4l-0 ia32-libs
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main libc6-i386 2.10.1-0ubuntu19
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.184 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main lib32z1 1:1.2.3.3.dfsg-13ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.184 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main lib32asound2 1.0.20-3ubuntu6.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.184 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main lib32ncurses5 5.7+20090803-2ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.184 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main lib32v4l-0 0.6.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.184 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/main libc6-i386 2.10.1-0ubuntu19
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/main lib32bz2-1.0 1.0.5-3ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/main lib32gcc1 1:4.4.1-4ubuntu9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/main lib32stdc++6 4.4.1-4ubuntu9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/universe ia32-libs 2.7ubuntu17.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6-i386_2.10.1-0ubuntu19_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bzip2/lib32bz2-1.0_1.0.5-3ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.4/lib32gcc1_4.4.1-4ubuntu9_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zlib/lib32z1_1.2.3.3.dfsg-13ubuntu3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.184 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.4/lib32stdc++6_4.4.1-4ubuntu9_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/lib32asound2_1.0.20-3ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.184 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/lib32ncurses5_5.7+20090803-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.184 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libv/libv4l/lib32v4l-0_0.6.0-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.184 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/ia32-libs/ia32-libs_2.7ubuntu17.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
```

I'm not too familiar with what happens to a system when it's reached end of life, but I can see the security repos are gone. Is there a way around this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

as you've noticed Karmic Koala has reached its end. It's no longer on that server.
Maybe you can find single packages 
as in https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/karmic/i386/libc6/2.10.1-0ubuntu19. By now I don't know if a 'old' repository exists.

Hope it helps