# I still have 9.04 but it's on an old computer without a cd burner. Pretty self explanatory...?

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I keep using Ubuntu 9.04 if it's outdated?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90929/can-i-keep-using-ubuntu-9-04-if-its-outdated)

I tried to upgrade (9.04 to 9.10 of course)... 'Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.'

Any suggestions or ways to work around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 9.10 is beyond EOL (End of Life). You might be able to upgrade if you specify the old mirror, but, realistically you are almost certainly better off installing Lubuntu 11.10.

For an older mirror, see [Can I keep using Ubuntu 9.04 if it's outdated?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90929/can-i-keep-using-ubuntu-9-04-if-its-outdated)

In the absence of a CD drive , can you boot a flash drive ? If so, you can make a bootable flash drive with [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) .

Answer (score 0):

bodhi.zazen was right on it with the lubuntu.  Don't forget that there are tons of other alternative distros to consider when dealing with an older computer.  When I'm trying to make better use of old hardware, the first disro I usually try is simply Debian.  I'll trial some different interfaces like lxde, xfce, fluxbox, and the like until I find one that works well with my machine's resources.
Ubuntu will also support lighter interfaces like the above.  In fact, I've got 11.10 installed to one of my development machines, but because it is close to 29,000 years old; I use the xfce environment.
like bodhi.zazen mentioned, you need to check into whether or not your machine is usb bootable.  If not, can you boot it from an sd card?
Another option is to learn some terminal kung fu.  Actually, if I were given the challenge to upgrade 9.04 to 9.10; as my only option.  I'd start with trying to hack it out from terminal first.