# Security updates for old-releases

Tags: apt, security

I know that I should upgrade to a newer supported Ubuntu version if possible, but:
**if you have no possibility to upgrade (for reasons not important here)**
you have to [use the old-releases archive](https://askubuntu.com/a/90936/34298) from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com to still be able to install some software.

Are those archives not touched at all? Or does Ubuntu sometimes still update them to solve fatal security issues with critical vulnerabilities like the "Heartbleed Bug" in the old releases?

Or **is there an alternative repository**, I could use in my `sources.list` on such an old system?

Or is there some list of fixes/backports, I could/should install on those old systems?

Comment: End of support means no updates, at all.

Comment: I know that, thats, Why I ask here for an alternative

Comment: You should just upgrade, there are extensive exploits for unmaintained older releases that will never be fixed, including kernel exploits.

Comment: I know that, but that is not the question here

Comment: This question is off-topic as we do not support end of life versions here. But to answer your question once a release goes end of life its archived and all development stops.  The developers have a hard enough time coping with the supported versions.  They are not going to patch software for an EOL release/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or is there an alternative repository, I could use in my sources.list on such an old system?

No.

> Or is there some list of fixes/backports, I could/should install on those old systems?

No.

End of life is end of life.

If you want an example: that certificate fiasco where all the SSL certs where revoked and we all had to update our systems and our servers. The changelog had fixes for all active releases. The end of life releases in between did NOT get a software update.

Comment: So no alternatives? maybe switching to debian or such a hack?

Comment: Nope. That would switch your system completely into a Debian system. Plus you would still need to use a not EOL release.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Ubuntu provides updates of any sort to EOL releases. If you look at the timestamps for the [13.04 `security` archives](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/), the last update was on January 23. Ubuntu 13.04 reached End-Of-Life on January 27, I believe. You can take a look at the `Packages` files to see, for example, which version of OpenSSL applies - and for 13.04, the applicable packages are all from January.

The only thing you should install on your system is an upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: So how/where could I still get **siome** updates for old-releases if I cannot upgrade (for reasons not important here)?

Comment: @rubo77 You can look around to see if some PPAs still offer support, or do so manually.