# Ubuntu-desktop won’t download

Tags: apt, software-installation, desktop-environments, 21.10

I accidentally deleted my ubuntu desktop and now I have no way of redownloading it. I’ve tried to do a `sudo apt update` and upgrade. When I type

```
Sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

I get the following issue:
Package ‘Ubuntu-desktop’ has no installation candidate. I tried everything including deleting the list file, cleaning, updating, upgrading, etc. please help

Version: Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I’m using Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: 21.10 has reached the end of life (EOL). It's repositories have been archived. As the repositories are not there, `apt` cannot download `Ubuntu-desktop`. Questions about EOL versions of Ubuntu are off topic here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: The way people answer questions on here is so condescending. It’s obvious I know how to type case sensitive command line prompts. The problem is not the case sensitivity otherwise it would have given a different error (duh). If you can’t help and don’t know how to resolve the problem, don’t be a jerk

Comment: At this point, this version of ubuntu is not anymore supported. Download Ubuntu 22.04 (supported until April 2027), and write it to a live USB. You can perform backup of any necessary files from the live environment, and then perform a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) End of Life reached on July 14 2022](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-July/000281.html).

Ubuntu 21.10 is no longer supported. It is archived to old-releases.ubuntu.com. You have edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change 'archive.ubuntu.com' to 'old-releases.ubuntu.com'.

This can be [done](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90929/can-i-keep-using-ubuntu-9-04-if-its-outdated) by typing

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

in the terminal. After running this command, run `sudo apt update && Sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. It is best you update to a newer and supported version of Ubuntu unless you have a very specific and genuine reason to stay on Ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trapped you can try installing an alternative DE like cinnamon or KDE. To install KDE use the following command

```
sudo apt install kde-plasma-desktop
```

or you can upgrade your desktop using the command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Hope this helps you.